# How to Place a Popup Control Over a ListBox

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, listbox, popup

After a certain condition has been met, I would like to place a Popup over a ListBox. When I do this in my following code, I am getting an `XamlParseException` on the `InitializeComponent()` in my page constructor. I am not sure why?

`EditPage.xaml`

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="ListBoxEffects" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="{Binding}" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" >
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                 <toolkit:WrapPanel ItemWidth="146" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="12,0,0,24" >
                     <Image Source="{Binding Thumbnail}" Width="134" Height="134" />
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                  </StackPanel>
              </DataTemplate>
         </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Popup x:Name="trialPopup">
        <Border Margin="3" BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}">
            <StackPanel Background="FF1BA1E2">
                 <TextBlock Text="Do you wish to purchase the application?" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10">
                     <Button x:Name="purchaseButton" Content="purchase" Click="popupButton_Click"/>
                     <Button x:Name="cancelButton" Content="cancel" Click="popupButton_Click"/>
                 </StackPanel>
             </StackPanel>
         </Border>
     </Popup>
</Grid>
```

For testing purposes I was just trying to show the popup immediately on navigation to the EditPage so I can see how it will look and theme it, but in production this will only show up after a certain requirement has been met. How might I actually get to test seeing the popup display over the ListBox?

Comment: of course you will get those exceptions, look at your stack panel background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by **See Sharp** in the comments, the issue is with the following line:

```
<StackPanel Background="FF1BA1E2">
```

The hash symbol (or number sign) must be used as a prefix for hexadecimal colours:

```
<StackPanel Background="#FF1BA1E2">
```

Also see this related answer for more detail: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1484842/247257

Comment: Is there a reason why when running this on my device the popup does not show up? Do I have to toggle the visibility of the ListBox and Popup accordingly? I really need the Popup to overlay the ListBox, how might I accomplish this?

Comment: you'll need to toggle the `IsOpen` property of the `Popup` control