# Range function getBackgrounds returns erroneous html color codes

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using this code snippet from the Google Apps script API:

```
function test() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var range = sheet.getRange("B5:C6");
var bgColors = range.getBackgrounds();
for (var i in bgColors) {
  for (var j in bgColors[i]) {
    Logger.log(bgColors[i][j]);
  }
}
}
```

However, when using the debug option the returned `bgColor`. Values seem to be erroneous. For instance, I get the following color codes:
`[["#ff00ff00", "#00ff00"], ["#ffff0000", "#ff00ff00"]]`

Note that the hexadecimal number for the RGB HTML color should be only six digits. Only `"#00ff00"` is correct. The rest of codes contain extra "ff" digits at the beginning. Is this a bug in the API?

Comment: This post can help you to find the answer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484834/why-the-leading-ff-in-hexadecimal-color-values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why the leading "#FF" in hexadecimal color values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484834/why-the-leading-ff-in-hexadecimal-color-values)